# Using Reflection to Create an Expression Tree from a Static Expression Method

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a method that uses an expression to define its output:

```
public async Task<TOut>
    GetCustomerAsync<TOut>(
        int customerId,
        Expression<Func<Models.Customer, TOut>> map)
{
    return await _customerService.GetMappedSingleAsync(
        map,
        customer => customer.Id == customerId;
}
```

I then have a number of different static *expression methods* that I can pass into this method, for example:

```
public static class CustomerExpressions
{
    public static Expression<Func<Models.Customer, CustomerItemDto>>
        CustomerItemDtoExpression()
    {
        return customer => new CustomerItemDto
        {
            CustomerId = customer.Id,
            CustomerName = customer.Name
        };
    }
}
```

The main method can then be called like this:

```
var customer = await _customerUiService.GetCustomerAsync(
    id, CustomerExpressions.CustomerItemDtoExpression());
```

I would now like to use *reflection* to create the expression tree from the designated expression method, so I could select the required expression by name.  Something like this:

```
var dtoName = "CustomerItemDto";
var methodName = dtoName + "Expression";
var classType = typeof(CustomerExpressions);
var method = classType.GetMethod(methodName);

var expressionTree = /* Create an expression tree from the method */

var customer = await _customerUiService
    .GetCustomerAsync(id, expressionTree);
```

In other words, how can I compile the *expression tree* from my method's MethodInfo?

Any help would be much appreciated.

### Update

So I have now got a little further with the code thanks to the comments

```
var dtoName = "CustomerItemDto";
var methodName = dtoName + "Expression";
var classType = typeof(CustomerExpressions);
var method = classType.GetMethod(methodName);

var expressionTree = method.Invoke(null, null);

// The problem now is that expressionTree is returned as an object,
// when, in this example, it needs to be of type
// Expression<Func<Models.Customer, TOut>>

var customer = await _customerUiService
    .GetCustomerAsync(id, expressionTree);
```

The problem now is that `expressionTree` is returned as an `object`, when it needs to be of type `Expression<Func<Models.Customer, TOut>>` - in this particular case the return type of the method `Expression<Func<Models.Customer, CustomerItemDto>>`

Comment: Just invoke it (method.Invoke(null))? It will return the desired expression

Comment: Thank you Evk, but this gives me a compiler error:

Cannot resolve method 'Invoke(null)', candidates are: object? Invoke(object?, object?[]?) (in class MethodBase) object? Invoke(object?, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder?, object?[]?, System.Globalization.CultureInfo?) (in class MethodBase)

Comment: If I invoke as method.Invoke(null,null), then that works but I then get the following error when I pass that expression to the main function:


.GetCustomerAsync<TOut>(int, Expression<Func<Customer,TOut>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Neilski, maybe you are looking for something like this? https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/pull/127

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - that is pretty much what I am trying to do, but my problem is how to build the generic expression tree and submit it as a parameter to the main method

Comment: @Neilski, `var expressionTree = (Expression<Func<Models.Customer, CustomerItemDto>>)method.Invoke(null, null);`
But later look closer at my solution from LINQKit PR.

Comment: Thank you @SvyatoslavDanyliv, but I think my use case is a little different, as I want to get the method by reflection, having done that, when I invoke the method I can't cast it to a typed return as I don't know what that is (as Invoke() returns an object).. If I try and pass the invoked expression tree object, the compiler emits an error as it is not of the expected generic type.

Comment: @Neilski, yes cases are different, but sometime people choose strange solutions ;)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - Ha ha, fair point :-)